# Why SelectedItem property does not work with ComboBoxItem strings?

Tags: combobox, wpf-controls, selecteditem

I want to select combobox items by their string value but I have a problem.
A simple test:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="text1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyListOfStrings}">
</ComboBox>
```

MyListOfStrings has list with strings "text1", "text2", "text3". This way it works fine - the text1 gets selected.

But the following way does not work:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="text1">
 <ComboBoxItem>text1</ComboBoxItem>
 <ComboBoxItem>text2</ComboBoxItem>
 <ComboBoxItem>text3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

What is wrong with it? Why WPF cannot find text1 if I define items in XAML?

P.S. Actually SelectedItem uses data binding, I just simplified the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the selected item with `Selector.IsSelected="True"` for that `ComboItem`

```
<ComboBox>
 <ComboBoxItem Selector.IsSelected="True">text1</ComboBoxItem>
 <ComboBoxItem>text2</ComboBoxItem>
 <ComboBoxItem>text3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Edit :

if you are using Binding, creat a ComboBoxItem property

```
 public ComboBoxItem MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            ComboBoxItem ci = new ComboBoxItem();
            ci.Content = "text1";
            return ci;
        }
    }
```

and Bind

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MyProperty}"
```

Comment: It would be great, but SelectedItem actually uses data binding, so I won't know which item is selected at design time.

Comment: then you should bind ComboBoxItem to SelectedItem

Answer (score 1):

I guess it doesn't work because ComboBoxItem is not a string, and there is no converter from string to ComboBoxItem.
But ComboBoxItem offers a "IsSelected" property that you could use.

Comment: hmm... actually SelectedItem is using binding, so it would be hard to bind each combobox item's IsSelected property. But maybe I could use some custom converter? Is there any way to create converter which converts SelectedItem string to the ComboBoxItem and back?